# Optimize query performance with multiple union

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

My requirement is to search particular text in selected tables.

But all the tables are of different structure for some columns i need to use join with multiple table for searching using ID and for some columns directly i can search through data

**I can achieve the above requirement using below query but is there any way to optimize the query and shorten the same**

```
 SELECT A.id, 
       Concat(A.fname, ' ', A.lname) AS NAME, 
       A.category 
FROM   dbo.employeedetail A 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues B 
              ON A.department = B.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues C 
              ON A.designation = C.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues D 
              ON A.esilocation = D.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues E 
              ON A.grade = E.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues F 
              ON A.costcentre = F.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues G 
              ON A.branch = G.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues H 
              ON A.location = H.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues I 
              ON A.esidispensary = I.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues J 
              ON A.ptlocation = J.id 
WHERE  ( code LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR fname LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR lname LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR mname LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR fathername LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR gender LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR maritalstatus LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR pfaccno LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR esino LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR panno LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR metro LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR address1 LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR address2 LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR place LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR city LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR pincode LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR phoneno LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_address1 LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_address2 LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_place LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_city LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_phone LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR corr_pincode LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR email LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR personalemail LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR personalmobileno LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR officemobileno LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR uannumber LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR B.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR C.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR D.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR E.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR F.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR G.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR H.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR I.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
          OR J.combovalue LIKE '%MAHARASHTRA%' ) 
UNION 
SELECT A.employeeid, 
       Concat(D.fname, ' ', D.lname) AS NAME, 
       D.category 
FROM   dbo.customefielddetail A 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.employeeconfig C 
              ON A.customefieldname = C.fieldname 
                 AND C.dfield = 'N' 
                 AND C.celltype = 'D' 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues B 
              ON A.fieldvalue = Cast(B.id AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                 AND B.fieldname = B.fieldname 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.employeedetail D 
              ON A.employeeid = D.id 
WHERE  B.combovalue LIKE '%maharashtra%' 
UNION 
SELECT A.employeeid, 
       Concat(D.fname, ' ', D.lname) AS NAME, 
       D.category 
FROM   dbo.customefielddetail A 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.employeedetail D 
              ON A.employeeid = D.id 
WHERE  A.fieldvalue LIKE '%maharashtra%'
```

Comment: Your `like` conditions can not make use of indexes. Do you have a fulltext index on the relevant columns and if so you can use CONTAINS so query. Then it should be really fast

Comment: @juergend Full text search is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

The first optimization you can easily implement is to replace `UNION` by `UNION ALL`. Keep in mind that `UNION` implicitly remove duplicate lines. So if you are confident in the fact that you won't get any duplicate values, this replacement should be a good optimization.

I hope it helps !